# OpenCL copyto() consumes more time

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, opencl, imread

I am comparing OpenCL `UMat` with that of OpenCL `Mat`, I run the `cvtColor()` function for 500 times.

```
int OpenCL_UMat()
{
    Mat img;
    UMat uimage, U1;
    img = imread("image_path");
    for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++)
    {
        img.copyTo(uimage); // Here it takes 1 sec
        cvtColor(uimage, U1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    imshow("image1", U1);
    return 0;
}

int OpenCL_Mat()
{
    Mat img, img1;
    img = imread("image_path");
    for (int i = 1; i < 500; i++)
    {
        cvtColor(img, img1, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    }
    imshow("image1", img);
    return 0;
}
```

The output for the code in microseconds is 
 _________________________________
| OpenCL UMat= 2368720 microseconds-|
|_________________________________|
|  OpenCL Mat  =  312200 microseconds----|
|_________________________________|

From the above code i found that `copyto()` function needs time to load the image from RAM on to GPU, so when the copyto() function runs, it consumes 1 sec to execute.

Is there any option, where i can directly make use of UMat.
 Something like this
 `UMat img = imread("image_path");`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
UMat img = imread("image_path").getUMat(ACCESS_READ);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How do i proceed with a webcamera? We can't use `.getUmat(ACCESS_READ)` when `VideoCapture` is used.

Comment: @SurakshaAjith VideoCapture has overloaded extraction operator `virtual VideoCapture& operator>>(UMat &image)`, so you can just get a frame like this: `capture >> frame`.